# React.JS pass role value from top menu page to sub page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the logon user's role infromation in the TopMenu.jxs

```
  getIsCurrentUserAdmin () {
    return _.some(this.props.currentUser.userRoles, ['roleId', 2]);
  },
  render: function () {
    let isCurrentUserAdmin = this.getIsCurrentUserAdmin();
```

How can I pass the value of isCurrentUserAdmin to my sub page, say `UserDetails.jxs`. Here userDetails mean that logon user is administrating other users' detailed information. 
Please help me. I am a newbie to React.JS

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you are looking to pass down data to a component using props.

You can do this like so

```
render: function() {
  const isCurrentUserAdmin = this.getIsCurrentUserAdmin();

  return <MyOtherComponent isAdmin={isCurrentUserAdmin} />;
}
```

You will also need to add isAdmin to the PropTypes of `MyOtherComponent`, however using prop types is beyond the scope of this question. [See the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) for a starting place about PropTypes

Comment: Thank, Spirift,  I have var UsersDetail = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    user: React.PropTypes.object,
    groups: React.PropTypes.object,
    ui: React.PropTypes.object,
    params: React.PropTypes.object,
    router: React.PropTypes.object,
  },

Comment: return <div id="header">
      <UsersDetail isAdmin={isCurrentUserAdmin} />;   was added to TopMeny.jsx  But when I use  (this.props.isAdmin) in UsersDetail, I got erorr: 'isAdmin' is missing in props validation. Do I need to do anything before using it in UsersDetail ?

Comment: You should add every prop to the prop types as well. Add isAdmin to the prop types and the Type that it is and the error will go away. `isAdmin: React.PropTypes.bool` I'm guessing that this prop is a Boolean.